# How to communicate between user-controls

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light, uwp

I'm trying to create master/detail UI, like in Win10 email app. I have split my app to `user controls`, and my problem is how to communicate between them.

> When user selects item from main list (which is inside pivot item
>   usercontrol), I want to display detailed info on the right side of the
>   main list.

**MainView.xaml** (simplified)

```
<Page>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="GridMainColumn" Width="400" />
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="GridDetailColumn" Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Pivot -->
        <Grid x:Name="GridPivot" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Pivot SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedPivotIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                   Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <PivotItem>
                    <view:CarsPivotItemView/>
                </PivotItem>
                <PivotItem>
                    <view:HotelsivotItemView/>
                </PivotItem>
            </Pivot>
        </Grid>

        <!-- Detailed view -->
        <Grid x:Name="GridDetail" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
            <view:CarDetailsView 
                  Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.CarSelected, 
                  Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <view:HotelDetailsView 
                  Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.HotelSelected, 
                  Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
<Page>
```

Note* `CarsPivotItemView` is user-control which has its own view model.

**CarsPivotItemView.xaml** (simplified)

```
<UserControl>
    <RelativePanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="SearchBox" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" Text="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:TextBoxEnterKeyBehavior>
                    <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding EnterKeyDownCommand}"/>
                </behaviors:TextBoxEnterKeyBehavior>
            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TextBox>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Cars}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar, Mode=TwoWay}" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.Below="SearchBox" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CarSelectedCommand}" />
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:ICar">
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,10,0,10">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind FullMakeModel}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </RelativePanel>
</UserControl>
```

**Now when user selects car from CarsPivotItemView ListView, I want to display CarDetailsView on MainView.**

How should I bind this selected car from **CarsPivotItemView to CarDetailsView**?

Should I use e.g. MVVM light Messenger to send message from CarsPivotItemViewViewModel to CarDetailsViewModel?

Overall, is this good idea to split this kind of pieces to user control?

*I'm using MVVM light and Template10 on my app.*

Comment: I would use messaging for this. It is the best way to decouple things like this.

Answer (score 0):

On the Cars ListView, it looks like the `SelectedItem` binding is pointing at a different binding source than everything else.

It should be `{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedCar, Mode=TwoWay}`. Then in the `setter for SelectedCar`, you can set `ViewModel.CarSelected = true`, which should display it in the details view

Comment: SelectedItem binding is pointing to CarsPivotItemView's ViewModel, but it is using regular binding (not compiled binding) as SelectedItem is an object and you can not bind it to ICar using compiled binding (maybe you need to use converted for that). In CarsPivotItemView.xaml there is data context set to ViewModel in xaml, but to keep example simple that was stripped away.

Comment: If you want to use compiled bindings for selected item, you do indeed need converter... I used it here https://github.com/AppCreativity/Kliva/blob/master/src/Kliva/Controls/ActivityFeedControl.xaml#L20 and the converter https://github.com/AppCreativity/Kliva/blob/master/src/Kliva/Converters/XBindItemCastingConverter.cs

Answer (score 0):

Windows App Studio team has good UWP samples in two ways:

1. The generated code you can get in their portal (http://appstudio.windows.com) where you can find good implementation patterns,
2. they have a github account where you can find a bunch of responsive controls and usage samples (https://github.com/wasteam/waslibs)